# OpenGL dont display multiple vertices loaded from STL file

Tags: opengl

I try to draw the 3D model from STL file. I am already successful to load the triangle mesh from CAD file, the loaded data is correct because I load the ASCII file. It is the sample of the loaded data

```
n 0.954709   -0.160052   -0.250827 
v1 4826.07   16113.6   2710.49 
v2 4826.26   16113.5   2711.21 
v3 4824.94   16108.2   2709.71 
n 0.87753   -0.142971   -0.457712 
v1 4825.89   16113.6   2709.76 
v2 4826.07   16113.6   2710.49 
v3 4824.94   16108.2   2709.71
```

Then I use the below code in painGL function to draw

```
   glViewport(0, 0, width(), height());
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
   glColor3f(1,1,0);
   glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
   for(int i=0;i<triangles.size;i++)
       {
       glNormal3f((GLfloat)triangles.normals[i].x,(GLfloat)triangles.normals[i].y,(GLfloat)triangles.normals[i].z);
       glVertex3f((GLfloat)triangles.vertices[0][i].x,(GLfloat)triangles.vertices[0][i].y,(GLfloat)triangles.vertices[0][i].z);
       glVertex3f((GLfloat)triangles.vertices[1][i].x,(GLfloat)triangles.vertices[1][i].y,(GLfloat)triangles.vertices[1][i].z);
       glVertex3f((GLfloat)triangles.vertices[2][i].x,(GLfloat)triangles.vertices[2][i].y,(GLfloat)triangles.vertices[2][i].z);
   }
   glEnd();
```

where triangle is the variable under struct

```
typedef struct
{
    VECTOR_3 vertices[3];
    VECTOR_3 normals;
    int size=0;
}STL_PARAMETERS;
```

But the widget didnt draw anythings. I try another draw triangle

```
glColor3f(1,1,0);
glScalef(1, 1, 0.0);
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
glVertex3f(0,-0.5,0);
glVertex3f(0.5,-0.5,0);
glVertex3f(0.0,0.5,0);
glEnd();
```

it drew correctly. I think I have problem with the coordinate or the scale of unit in OpenGL, because the loaded vertices value is very big.
Is there any solution to solve my problem?

Comment: Since the vertex values are so large, perhaps you are rendering out of view? You could try changing the view point by "zooming out" using `gluLookAt()`. Or I suppose maybe normalizing the vertex values by dividing by the max (~16000) would make the model smaller as well. Just don't scale the normals.

Comment: Do you by any chance mean triangles[i].vertices[0] ... instead of triangles.vertices[0][i] ... in your 1st code snippet?

Comment: @PavelBeliy: I push back the normals and vertices inside triangles, not push_back the triangles variable, so that may code is not wrong.